# How to Load RevMob before another Task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, revmob

i am working on Revmob and i got stuck at position that i want to load RevMob before executing another task, My code part is this

```
play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // Starting RevMob session
            revmob = RevMob.start(Home.this, REVMOB_APP_ID);
            revmob.setTestingMode(RevMobTestingMode.WITH_ADS);

            // revmob.showPopup(this);
            revmob.showFullscreen(Home.this);// should appear first then later
            Intent i=new Intent(Home.this,LevelSelect.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

What is happening here,the activity is intented and then revmob appears.Also implemented AsynTask,,,,, but couldn't get the job done

Comment: I don't understand your problem, your say that revmob appears so what is wrong?

Comment: Yeah its appearing,,,, but the problem is that,,the intent is executing firstly and then revmob appears,,